# Google pop up closed by user

Tags: html, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to make a system to get the email of the current user to verify if it's in a list of emails and if it is let it into the website. But whenever i click on the google sign in button it closes and gives me that error.

I have searched the internet far and wide for an answer but I cannot find one. I've remade my client ID dozens of times to see if that was a problem. I am also getting an error in the logs saying "Error: null" that only appears when i put in the code to show the button.

This is my code;

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="201822045397-b8k83v6ang79rlfo8009vpr1nnse7bsl.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-ux_mode="redirect"></div>
  <script>
    function onSuccess() {
    if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
  var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
  console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
}
    function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting these errors;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Uncaught
{error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}
details
:
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Comment: have you reviewed the migration guide?